# refactoring rails method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

I was wondering, how could i refactor this code, because it doesn't looks good to read and understand

```
def next_payment_price
    price = self.plan_price
    price = discounted_price if self.coupon && self.coupon_duration.nil? && self.coupon_discount != 100
    price = discounted_price if self.coupon && self.coupon_duration.present? && self.coupon_discount != 100 && ((self.created_at + 14.days + self.coupon_duration.month)  > Time.now )
    price
end

def discounted_price
    self.plan_price - ((self.plan_price * self.coupon_discount) / 100)
end
```

Comment: extract this in your coupon class

Comment: can't be achieved, because coupon can be changed, while in this class i have static data, that will be used for calculations

Comment: yes... but you can init a coupon object with your details, remind: decouple your lpgic, create objects with their own responsibilities. (Basically, people encouraging you to keep the logic in your model don;t follow these guidelines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use smaller methods for better reading

```
  def next_payment_price
    correct_discount? && correct_coupon? ? discounted_price : self.plan_price
  end

  def expired_coupon?
    (self.created_at + 14.days + self.coupon_duration.month)  < Time.now
  end

  def correct_coupon?
    self.coupon_duration.nil? || (self.coupon_duration && !expired_coupon?)
  end

  def correct_discount?
    self.coupon && self.coupon_discount && self.coupon_discount < 100
  end

  def discounted_price
    self.plan_price - self.plan_price * self.coupon_discount / 100
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create little methods inside the `coupon` model, that gives the object more meaning like:

```
def is_less_than_100?
  self.coupon_discount != 100
end

def is_date_bigger_than_today?
  (self.created_at + 14.days + self.coupon_duration.month)  > Time.now
end
```

This way you will have less code, and it will be easier to understand:

```
price = discounted_price if self.is_less_than_100? and self.is_date_bigger_than_today?
```

P.S.: The names are just for demonstrating the purpose. I think you got the idea

Answer (score 1):

What if you plucked out the expiration logic into a method as well?

```
    def not_expired?
        return false if self.coupon_duration.nil?
        ((self.created_at + 14.days + self.coupon_duration.month)  > Time.now )
    end
```

Then:

```
    def next_payment_price
        price = self.plan_price
        price = discounted_price if self.coupon? and not_expired? ...
    end
```